# Заполнитель php

Tags: php

Имеется выражение `$arFields["CODE"] = $arFields["PROPERTY_VALUES"][9][*]["VALUE"];` 
 * - может принимать любое значение, как это записать?.
%i или что-то похожее( %i не работает)?

Comment: такого не бывает, вы же записываете в $arFields["CODE"] какое-то определенное значение $arFields["PROPERTY_VALUES"][9][*]["VALUE"]. То есть вы должны к нему обратиться, а если вы хотите взять любое рандомное например число, но используйте функцию rand. А так откуда программа знает, что вы туда подставить хотите. Если эт ов цикле, то используйте инкремент например. Либо передавайте туда переменную, а выше в переменную записывайте, то что вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```html
foreach ($arFields["PROPERTY_VALUES"][9] as $articul) {
  $elementArticle = $articul["VALUE"];
}
```

$articul = * ($articul принимает любые значения: n0 ... 101311)

Comment: даже интересно, как вы раньше пробовали `%i` использовать :D

Comment: я даже не мог представить, что можно так не грамотно отнестись к составлению вопроса, у вас $arFields["PROPERTY_VALUES"][9][*] не принимает любые значения, а вы выполняете выборку элементов массива $arFields["PROPERTY_VALUES"][9] не зная его содержания глубже

Comment: Хотел использовать что-то вроде заполнителя. Не $arFields["PROPERTY_VALUES"][9][*] принимает любые значения, а * - читайте внимательней